# Предупреждение pyCharm для аннотаций

Tags: pycharm, python-3.7

Реализовал класс, который похож на этот:

```
@dataclass
class Solver:
    c: float

    def __init__(self):
        self.c = None
```

PyCharm ругает так:

> This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations.

Можно ли для типа указать `None` так, чтобы не было предупреждений? Компиляция происходит и всё замечательно выполняется. Но в чём ошибка? [Здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/415829/) использовался аналогичный подход

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Следует использовать следующую конструкцию:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional

@dataclass
class Solver:
    c: Optional[float]

    def __init__(self):
        self.c = None
```